# fadein and out images randomly without page reload or refresh

Tags: jquery

I was stuck into jquery and need some help

```
Here is my code:

JQUERY:

var doms = [];
var randos = [];
var index = 0;

window.fadeout = function() {
  if (index < 3) {
    var random = $(doms.get(randos[index]));
    $(random).delay(200 * index).fadeTo(200, 0, function() {
      $(random).css("visibility", "hidden");
    });
    doms = doms.not(random);
    index++;
    fadeout(doms);
  }
}

var selected = $(this);
doms = $('.grid-item');
var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * doms.length);
for (var i = 0; i < doms.length; i++) {
  while (randos.indexOf(num) > -1) {
    num = Math.floor(Math.random() * doms.length);
  }
  randos.push(num);
}
fadeout();

HTML:

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item">Image 1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Image 2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Image 3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Image 4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Image 5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Image 6</div>
</div>
```

This code randomly fadein and out images but on page reload or refresh. I need that images should fadein fade out automatically after a span of time without any page refresh.

```
FRONTEND:
Actually my output at frontend is like this:

Image1  Image2  Image3

Image4  Image5  Image6

I want it to be in this type of patterns that forms triangle .i.e

Image1           Image3

         Image5

     or

Image1

Image4   Image5

     or
        Image2

image4          Image6

Like so...
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8rx7mfw5/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
    setInterval(function(){ 

       $('#someId').fadeIn();

    }, 3000);

    setInterval(function(){ 

       $('#someId').fadeOut();

    }, 4000);
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/gogx8a44/1/)

Comment: where should I add this code in my jQuery code? Thanks in advance

Comment: into this script only onready function <script> </script> Like $(document).ready(function(){ }). If you want it will be click event write function name(){}. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks Hossain. Can you please help in how to have only three images at a time. –

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like

```js
var $doms = $('.grid-item'),
  array = [0, 1, 2];
$doms.slice(3).hide();
setInterval(function() {
  var hide = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length),
    num;
  $doms.eq(array[hide]).css("visibility", "visible").fadeTo(200, 1);
  array.splice(hide, 1);
  do {
    num = Math.floor(Math.random() * $doms.length);
  } while (hide == num || array.indexOf(num) > -1);
  $doms.eq(num).fadeTo(200, 0, function() {
    $(this).css("visibility", "hidden");
  });
  array.push(num);
}, 500)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item">Image 1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Image 2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Image 3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Image 4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Image 5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Image 6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Arun You saved my time. Can you please suggest how to get only three images at a time. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use [jQuery setInterval function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

```
setInterval(function(){
    alert("Hello");
 }, 3000);
```

Comment: Just call your function in second line, if you make a fiddle for the same i can suggest you:)